# bindStore breaks combobox

Tags: javascript, extjs, ext3

Among the other form fields i have(the combobox is an extension of the standard combobox with  extra config options):

```
   marker: new Forms.ui.ComboBox({
    fieldLabel: _('Marker'),
    displayField: 'name',
    valueField: 'id',
    store: new Ext.data.JsonStore({
      fields: ['name', 'id','resellerid'],
      data: [
        {'name':_('Default'), 'id': 0, 'resellerid': 0}
      ]
    })
   })
```

Now when i need to use bindStore in a function that is called separately and has a jsonStore passed to it(store):

```
this.fields.marker.bindStore(store);
```

However, while the store is populated - im unable to select anything. I moved the store to the same script to test it - and set it directly to the combobox config as 'store:' - it works.

So the problem comes from bindstore  it seems.
What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it  was the quotes around the data property names that broke it.